# Block trial version if user has no enough money

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am currently developing a SaaS with a trial version and subscriptions at 200€/month. I would like to know if it is possible to make sure that a customer who takes advantage of a trial offer has enough money on his card to pay the subscription.

That is to say that I would like to block access to the trial version if the card does not have 200€. Is this possible with Stripe?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, no.

I mean, you could do an [auth on the card](https://support.stripe.com/questions/using-authorization-and-capture-with-paymentintents) to see if it had the funds available, but that would only be true at the moment it occurred and doesn't ensure that the funds will be available when the trial ends.